# QGIS 2.12.1 - Problem with Size Assistant in „data defined override“ Button - Error message

Tags: qgis, point, qgis-2.12, scale-factor

While trying out the Size Assistant feature I encountered a problem. 
I´m working with this csv Table:

[image: Used csv table]

I tried to resize the Point Size based on the field „Anzahl Objk“ and to do this I went to „Layer Properties“ – „Style“  clicked on the Data defined override Button next to the „Size field“ and selected „Size assistant“ at the bottom.
In the following window I changed the settings like this:

[image: Size Assistant Settings]

I clicked o.k. expecting to see values from 1 to 5 in the size of the yellow dot with the no „5“ next to it in the picture above. values from 6 up would then be in the size of the dot with the „10“ next to it.
After clicking o.k I got a red tinged button like this next to  the size field

[image: Error indicated next to size field]

And hoovering over it and in the description window it reports the following error:

[image: Error description]

If I click on Edit in the button menu I get to the expression builder where it reports the same error.

The points on the map don´t change at all.
Is there a way to get this to work easily the way I expect it to with this assistant by doing steps differently or do I have to enter or change an expression code somewhere?
Or do I completely misunderstand the dialog above and what it is supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click the *Edit* button to get the expression builder, you might see an expression like:

[image: Expression string builder]

Try putting the field name inside double quotation marks ( " " ) like this:

[image: Expression string builder with correct expression]

The error *should* disappear and hopefully you will see your points.

Comment: works, thanks for the help! Should I report this as a bug somewhere?

Comment: @Taya - Most welcome! I would think it is a bug, they did update the _Field Calculator_ to take into account field names **without** the need for the double-quotes but it seems this wasn't extended to the _Expression string builder_. If you wanted to, you can send a [bug report](https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis), note that you will need to create an account beforehand :)